# Unable to preview Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I am unable to preview Port 3000 after running the "rails s" command using Nitrous.IO, Firefox, Windows 7 and corporate internet.

The preview generated tab has the message, "Problem loading page. Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ror-magic-19568.apse1.actionbox.io:3000."

Previewing with different ports with "rails s --port=port" command are not working as well.

However preview works fine with Nitrous.IO, Firefox, Mac and private home internet. 
Any suggestion to make it work with my Windows 7 computer? Thanks.

From the console:

```
action@ror-magic-19568:~/projects/learn-rails(master*)$ rails s                                                                                                                                              
=> Booting     WEBrick                                                                                                                                                                                           
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000                                                                                                                                    
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                                                                                                                                                            
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                                                                                                 
[2013-08-01 01:21:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1                                                                                                                                                                    
[2013-08-01 01:21:52] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]                                                                                                                                          
[2013-08-01 01:21:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=32467 port=3000
```

Comment: So it works on your home network but not at work? Maybe something is blocking or using port 3000 on the corporate network?

Comment: Try to disable firewall if any

Comment: Or try to run it on port 80, in case your company network blocks outgoing requests over port 3000.

Comment: It is just too bad that I don't have access to the corporate network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nitrous boxes only have HTTP ports 3000 - 9000 open, so you will want to run rails on one of these ports which are open on the corporate network.